# Google map shows gray background unless you resize it

Tags: javascript, maps

This is on a modal.

I've seen other solutions to add the resize event on google map after the map is loaded but it doesn't work.

I tried this

```
setTimeout(function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}, 3000)
```

and it  still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The map might be hidden at first so you need to initiate the map again when the map is shown